# table app_shop_boughtitem has no column named buyer_id Django

Tags: django

Can you explain me, why I have this error? I think migration should solve this problem, but it doesn't. How can I solve this problem?

My model:

```
class BoughtItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Название товара или акции', blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Цена', blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Покупатель')
```

This migration:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('app_shop', '0002_item'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='BoughtItem',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, verbose_name='Название товара или акции')),
                ('price', models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Цена')),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('buyer', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='Покупатель')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the latest files in the migrations folder of the app then makemigrations again and migrate. Also try to put related_name param in the ForeignKey field like: `models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Покупатель', related_name='bought_items')`

Comment: I've tried all things that you recommended but it didn't help. What else can I do?

Comment: I dont know then. Maybe you did something wrong while setting up the app but I am not sure. Consider deleting your recent migration files and running old ones again.